# only use extended join-clause if some variable is TRUE

Tags: postgresql, join, plpgsql, postgis

I am working with Postgis (extension to postgres) where there are several different geometry-types, i.e. 'polygons', 'points' 'linestrings', and multi-variants of these.

I am trying to create a function which should only use extra join-clauses if the geometry-type is a (multi)-polygon.
in all cases, with all geometrytypes, the join should look like this:

```
--drop function if exists test_return(geometry, double precision);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_return(
      PAR_geom                      geometry
     ,PAR_tolerance                 double precision DEFAULT 0.0000001
) RETURNS setof geometry
AS $$
DECLARE
    VAR_main_id int;
BEGIN

CASE ST_GeometryType(PAR_geom)
WHEN 'ST_LineString'  THEN
    VAR_main_id = 0;
WHEN 'ST_Polygon', 'ST_MultiLineString', 'ST_MultiPoint'  THEN
    VAR_main_id = 1;
WHEN 'ST_MultiPolygon' THEN 
    VAR_main_id = 2;
ELSE 
    raise EXCEPTION 'this function does not work on single-points';
END CASE;

return query
with repeated_pts as (
select (st_dumppoints(PAR_geom)).path, (st_dumppoints(PAR_geom)).geom 
where st_npoints(st_snaptogrid(PAR_geom, PAR_tolerance)) <> st_npoints(PAR_geom)
)   

select b.geom from 
repeated_pts a
inner join
repeated_pts b
on 

--- Here is how it should behave for all geometry-types---
a.path[1:VAR_main_id] = b.path[1:VAR_main_id] 
and 
a.path[array_upper(a.path, 1)]< b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] 
and 
st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, PAR_tolerance);
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In case its a (multi)-polygon, i want to extend the join-clause with additional join-clauses:

```
and
  
(
(
a.path[VAR_main_id] = 1 and 
a.path[array_upper(a.path, 1)] > 1 and 
b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] > 1
)
or
(
a.path[VAR_main_id] > 1 and 
b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] <= 4 
)
)
```

Is there a smart way to do this?

I know its possible to insert the query into a case-when-then structure like this:

```
case 
when st_geometrytype(PAR_geom) in ('ST_MultiPolygon', 'ST_Polygon')
then --- run query with additional join-clause -- 

else 
-- run query WITHOUT the extra join-clause --
end case;
```

however, this structure requires I write the first part of the query twice - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The question shows where you got stuck with a presumed *solution*. Please start by describing what the function is trying to achieve (the actual *problem*). And disclose the (relevant parts of) the table definition and your version of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ErwinBrandstetter, it gave me a solution!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and then mark it as correct - no points I'm afraid! :-(, but it may help others with your problem! I'm voting to close, but if you provide your answer, I'll vote to reopen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In case its a (multi)-polygon, I want to extend the join-clause with additional join-clauses:

What you ask for can be achieved with plain boolean logic in the `JOIN` clause. Append:

```sql
AND ((st_geometrytype(PAR_geom) IN ('ST_MultiPolygon', 'ST_Polygon')) IS NOT TRUE

  OR a.path[VAR_main_id] = 1
 AND a.path[array_upper(a.path, 1)] > 1
 AND b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] > 1

  OR a.path[VAR_main_id] > 1
 AND b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] <= 4 
)
```

Meaning, either the type is not among the listed ones `('ST_MultiPolygon', 'ST_Polygon')`, or the following conditions have to be met.

Operator precedence makes `AND` bind before `OR`, so we need no additional parentheses.

The function might look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_return(par_geom      geometry
                                     , par_tolerance float8 = 0.0000001)
  RETURNS SETOF geometry
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   var_main_id int;
BEGIN
   CASE ST_GeometryType(par_geom)
   WHEN 'ST_LineString'  THEN
       var_main_id = 0;
   WHEN 'ST_Polygon', 'ST_MultiLineString', 'ST_MultiPoint'  THEN
       var_main_id = 1;
   WHEN 'ST_MultiPolygon' THEN 
       var_main_id = 2;
   ELSE 
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'this function does not work on single-points';
   END CASE;

   RETURN QUERY
   WITH repeated_pts AS (
      SELECT d.path, d.geom 
      FROM   st_dumppoints(par_geom) d  -- evaluate once
      WHERE  st_npoints(st_snaptogrid(par_geom, par_tolerance)) <> st_npoints(par_geom)
   )   
   SELECT b.geom
   FROM   repeated_pts a
   JOIN   repeated_pts b ON a.path[1:var_main_id] = b.path[1:var_main_id] 
                        AND a.path[array_upper(a.path, 1)] < b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] 
                        AND st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, par_tolerance)
                        -- append here!
                        AND ((st_geometrytype(PAR_geom) IN ('ST_MultiPolygon', 'ST_Polygon')) IS NOT TRUE

                          OR a.path[VAR_main_id] = 1
                         AND a.path[array_upper(a.path, 1)] > 1
                         AND b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] > 1

                          OR a.path[VAR_main_id] > 1
                         AND b.path[array_upper(b.path, 1)] <= 4 
                        );
END
$func$
```

Might be possible to simplify further. I lack insight.